# Run ADB command using android program

Tags: android, process, runtime, adb

I used

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\Android\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools\\adb.exe forward tcp:7777 tcp:7777");
```

for port forwarding in adb using android program. But it shows

```
 Exception :: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands: [C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe, forward, tcp:7777, tcp:7777] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

what is the problem about the code?? Anyone can help me please..........

Comment: r u running it in android emulator

Comment: No.... It's on device..... Android tablet.. Thanks for response...

Comment: the path is correct ?  could you access the adb.exe from your device ? And I think your adb.exe is a Win32 application, how can you running it on your device?

Comment: ya.... the path is correct....

Comment: plz have a look this site.... http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/